# Proof of Hales–Jewett number

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

In the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem, and the Polymath site http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Coloring_Hales-Jewett_theorem, it says that the Hales–Jewett number $H(3, 2)=4$. However, I am unable to construct a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube with two colours which avoids a combinatorial line of the same colour. If the Polymath site is correct, then there is such a colouring.

So my question is: Is there a colouring, and if so, what is it?

Comment: "...with two colours which avoids a combinatorial line of the same colour". I think the point of the theorem is that there is at least one combinatorial line that has only one color on it

Comment: Only when the dimension is high enough though. That was why I was confused when they said H(3, 2) = 4. That implies that a monochromatic combinatorial line is unavoidable in 4 dimensions but not in 3. Therefore, there should be a way to avoid it in 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a valid coloring of the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube.

[image: HJ cube]

The $(1,1,1)$ cell is the bottom left cell of the leftmost square.

Note the antidiagonal line in the third square with all three cells colored red. (And another antidiagonal line in the first square with all three cells colored blue. There might be more.) This is okay, because it's not a combinatorial line: one coordinate is increasing while another is decreasing.

If you consider the geometric variant of Hales-Jewett, and forbid any three collinear cells from having the same color, then my SAT solver tells me that there is no valid coloring.

---

**Edit:** A less ad-hoc way of coloring the cube than the above (which was found by a SAT solver) is to use the lower bound from van der Waerden's theorem. We can color the set $\{1, 2, \dots, 7\}$ red and blue while avoiding monochromatic arithmetic progressions of length $3$: color $\{1,3,6\}$ red and $\{2,4,5,7\}$ blue. Then color the $3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube by giving $(x,y,z)$ the color of $x+y+z-2$. This produces the following coloring (with "layers" of $x+y+z=c$ indicated by shading):

[image: VdW induced coloring]

So now it's straightforward to check that this coloring works. We can extend the coloring of $\{1, 2, \dots, 7\}$ to $\{1, 2, \dots, 8\}$ by coloring $8$ red, but to color the $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3$ cube, we would need a coloring of $\{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$, which (unsurprisingly) doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, I was considering the geometric version. A friend and I noticed that it was possible to create a 4x4x4 cube without a 4 in a row, and we guessed that it was impossible in 4 dimensions, and in general, it is impossible to get an n in a row in an n dimensional nxnxn... hyper-cube. Does that guess work out in higher n?

Comment: Even for the geometric version, I know of a coloring of the $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4$ hypercube without a $4$ in a row, and I would guess that the true bound is much higher. (In general, we have an exponential in $n$ lower bound on the geometric version of Hales-Jewett, just as we do on the combinatorial version.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a $2-$coloring of a $3×3×3$ cube which avoids a combinatorial line of the same colour.

The bottom layer is colored as:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0& 1 & 0  \\ \hline
0& 0& 1 \\ \hline
1&  0& 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

The middle layer is colored as:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0& 0 & 1  \\ \hline
 1& 1& 0\\ \hline
 0&  1& 0\\ \hline
\end{array}

The top layer is colored as:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
1& 1 & 0  \\ \hline
 0& 0& 1 \\ \hline
 1&  0& 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

We can easily check manually that the $4$ body diagonals are not monochromatic as well. Hence, this is the desired coloring!